# how to send more than 1 arg to JS function within a string?

Tags: javascript, function

***updat***
 the function name wasnt the problem (accidently copied wrong)
the problem was that i was sending string!
thanks to  **mplungjan** problem solved!!

this is my code:

```
 $("#GVHistory").append("<tr><td>" + order.OrderID +"</td><td><a href='#dialogHistory' id='ShowDet' data-role='button' data-transition='pop' onclick='function(" + order.OrderID +"," + order.Total + ")'>Details</a></td></tr>");
```

I have a JavaScript function:

```
function fun(id,t) {
    $("#HistHead").empty();
    $("#HistHead").append(t + id);
}
```

when I send 1 argument it works good, but more than 1 it fails.
Plus the data-roll doesn't effects, any thoughts?

Comment: That is because you are sending one string and not two arguments and have an issue with the name too - try `onclick='fun(order.OrderID,order.Total)'` -  If you want to pass the current order stuff: `onclick='fun(\"'+order.OrderID+'\",\"'+order.Total+'\")'`

Comment: wrong function name? it is supposed to be `fun` in onclick...

Comment: mplungjan Thank you!! that was my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is named **fun** and not **function**. Please make sure to use the right name in the onclick event.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

in your onclick event in the html, the function is "function" whereas the function is called "fun".

The following code works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="HistHead">Test</div>
    <table id="GVHistory"></table>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        order ={OrderID:12,Total:15};
        $("#GVHistory").append("<tr><td>" + order.OrderID +"</td><td><a href='#dialogHistory' id='ShowDet' data-role='button' data-transition='pop' onclick='fun(" + order.OrderID +"," + order.Total + ")'>Details</a></td></tr>");

    });
    function fun(id,t) {
        $("#HistHead").empty();
        $("#HistHead").append(t + id);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding, i want to explain in more detail.
Let's assume: order.OrderID = "orderId1" and order.Total = "total100"

At the moment where you append this `<tr>` to the DOM,  the **value** of  `order.OrderID` and `order.Total` are appended to your onclick function, not the variables.

Your onclick was rendered to `onclick="fun(orderId1, total100)"` If you click this, you will get an error, because the variable orderId1 and variable total100 are not defined. The right solution was to add some kind of quotes, to get two strings. You have to escape the quotes with \ otherwise the quotes will destroy the string that you are trying to append, in your first code snippet.

Calling click functions inline is always a bit messy and specially if you want to hand over more than one string or variables. I always take custom data attributes. `data-xxx="xxx"` to hand over something.

```
$("#GVHistory").append("<tr><td>" + order.OrderID +"</td><td><a href='#dialogHistory' class='ShowDet ui-btn' data-transition='pop'  data-orderid='"+order.OrderID+"' data-ordertotal='"+order.Total+"'>Details</a></td></tr>");

$(".ShowDet").unbind("click").on("click", function (){
    var id = $(this).data("orderid");
    var t = $(this).data("ordertotal");

    $("#HistHead").empty().append(t + id);
});
```

To your second problem with `data-role="button"`
This custom jquery mobile attribute, does only something if it's inside the DOM when the page is loaded the first time. If you want to append someting dynamically, you have to call the corresponding widget. In case of the button you just have to call `$(".ShowDet").button()` to intitalize the button markup. But a much easier way for buttons is to use the css classes to style them. `.ui-btn`